# Kube-proxy pod not starting v1.21.3

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, kubectl

I have delete `kube-proxy` pod from my master nodes to get the new kube-proxy configmap values, when I reboot the node still kube-proxy is not coming up ?

How to start the `kube-proxy`?

```
# crictl ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               CREATED             STATE               NAME                ATTEMPT             POD ID
19376bdbc55eb       c4d75af7e098e       17 minutes ago      Running             calico-node         2                   b4fb351577dd4
24253bf076500       6be0dc1302e30       17 minutes ago      Running             kube-scheduler      4                   182f9024a6957
57c5c9dec4ad2       3d174f00aa39e       17 minutes ago      Running             kube-apiserver      3                   e549a2bad6a02
```

**Cluster information:**

```
Kubernetes version: v1.21.3
Cloud being used: (put bare-metal if not on a public cloud)
Installation method: bare-metal
Host OS: CentOS Stream 8
CNI and version: Calico
CRI and version: containerd
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to `ClusterCIDR` IP change `kube-controller-manager` was in  `CrashLoopBackOff`  status. once I updated the old IP in `ClusterCIDR`,  `kube-controller-manager` pod started, then `kube-proxy` came up.